# Get multiple Root elements with XDocument

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have an XML file that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Page1>
  <item name="somefield1">111</item>
  <item name="somefield1">111</item>
</Page1>
<Page2>
  <item name="somefield1">111</item>
  <item name="somefield1">111</item>
</Page2>
<Page3>
  <item name="somefield1">111</item>
  <item name="somefield1">111</item>
</Page3>
```

I want to get all the `Root` element names. So in this case: `Page1`, `Page2` and `Page3`. But the amount of elements and their name can be anything.

But i can't figure out how to get all the names of the root elements. How can i do this with `Xdocument`?

Comment: You can't. An xml can not contain multiple root elements.

Comment: You don't have an XML file. You have something which *looks* a bit like an XML file, but has multiple root elements, and therefore isn't a (valid) XML file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are asking for is impossible. It is incorrect XML to have more than 1 root element, so `System.Xml.*` classes do not support that.

What you can do is put a root element around your `Page` elements:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Pages>
    <Page1>
      <item name="somefield1">111</item>
      <item name="somefield1">111</item>
    </Page1>
    <Page2>
      <item name="somefield1">111</item>
      <item name="somefield1">111</item>
...
</Pages>
```

and then it's easy to find, right under that element, your collection of Pages.

Comment: I see. I fixed it with `Doc.Elements("Pages").Elements();`. Thanks.